# Using @Around annotation on ExceptionHandler cause NullPointerException on ProceedingJoinPoint

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, aop, spring-aop

I've wrote an AOP aspect that will intercept on my Global exception handler, but it gives an unexpected behavior as proceeding join point is null and it cause `NullPointerException` when I tried to get arguments from it.

```
   @Around("execution(*    common.controller.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleException(..))")
public Object performTransactionIdCollectingFromGlobalExceptionHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object[] arguments = pjp.getArgs();
    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    {
        if (KioskProcessorException.class.isAssignableFrom(arguments[i].getClass()))
        {
            Long trId = ((KioskProcessorException) arguments[i]).getTransactionId();
            if(trId != null) {
                String transactionId = trId.toString();
                ThreadContext.put("trId", transactionId);
            }
        }
    }
    Object returnObj = pjp.proceed();
    ThreadContext.clearMap();
    return returnObj;
}
```

My Global Exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "base")
 public class GlobalExceptionHandler
{
@Autowired
private IErrorMappingService service;

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public BaseControllerResponseEntity handleException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Exception ex)
{
     //handle exception here

}
```

}

The problem is when global exception handler got called it returns an error below which implies that the pjp is null:

```
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver | Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public    tmn.kiosk.processor.common.controller.model.BaseControllerResponseEntity   tmn.kiosk.processor.common.controller.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleException(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.Exception)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at  tmn.kiosk.processor.common.aspect.LoggingAspect.performTransactionIdCollectingFromGlobalExceptionHandler(LoggingAspect.java:135) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor356.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607) ~[?:2.6 (08-23-2013)]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at tmn.kiosk.processor.common.aspect.LoggingAspect.performLogging(LoggingAspect.java:27) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607) ~[?:2.6 (08-23-2013)]
```

Comment: Which line exactly is `LoggingAspect.java:135`?

Comment: @luboskrnac Object[] arguments = pjp.getArgs();